# AWS Cognito Health Check

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have an NodeJs application that uses Cognito to manage the users and auth operations (design choice).
I am using 'amazon-cognito-identity-js' to communicate with Cognito but i'm having some trouble in making a simple health check api.

Since Cognito doesn't provide any API for that i thought of making a test user, pass the credentials to my app via env vars and try to login. If the result was a success it means that cognito is up and running.
Before i implement my solution i wanted to ask if there may be a better alternative to check if cognito is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this was quite simple. I just needed to check if i can reach Cognito's GET /login endpoint.

You can find the documentation about the endpoint [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/login-endpoint.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to events from the Health Service in CloudWatch Event Rules. You can then either send an email, SMS or even trigger lambda to perform an action if Cognito service is down.